# Bootstrap Confidence Bands/Simultaneous Confidence Intervals for GEE Logistic Model

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, bootstrap, generalized-estimating-equations

I have a relatively complex logistic model I built using generalized estimating equations (GEE).  The model is used to predict population mortality.  I have gone about estimating the mortality in the population by (1) fitting a model to my data, (2) making individual-level predictions of mortality from the data, and finally by (3) taking the mean of these predictions.  I am particularly interested in examining the shape of the model as I vary one predictor, holding all other variables constant.  To this end, I need to calculate a confidence band around the population prediction function from my model.  I can calculate population prediction intervals just fine (using the advice given by @Ben Bolker here [Parametric Bootstrap without model refitting?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176366/parametric-bootstrap-without-model-refitting)), but now I'm trying to figure out how I might be able to bootstrap confidence bands/simultaneous confidence intervals instead of just bootstrap point-wise confidence intervals.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This does not involve the bootstrap, but the R `rms` package's `contrast` and `Predict` functions can provide simultaneous confidence intervals on cluster sandwich covariance based estimates, by assuming multivariate normality of $\hat{\beta}$.  `plot.Predict` makes plots such as what you mentioned easy to do.

Comment: Hi, @FrankHarrell, thanks for this reference.  Can you tell me if `rms` will work for GEE models?  I have the second edition of your book right here, but I don't see any GEE model examples.

Comment: `rms` implements GEE with working independence covariance assumptions.  Fit the multiple record per subject model using any of the `rms` fitting functions then run the fit through `robcov` to get a robust cluster sandwich covariance estimator to take intra-subject correlation into account.  Then `contrast` and `Predict` can compute simultaneous confidence regions based on assuming multivariate normality of the GEE $\hat{\beta}$.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for your guidance, @FrankHarrell.  I'll give it a shot!  Much appreciated!